# How to print modified AST without actually perform the change?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

For Eclipse plug-in using CDT, i'm performing traversals over the AST. For a specific node (function, statement, ...) i would like to record modifications and to print the updated node without actually perform the change.

How can i achieve this?

I was thinking about using ASTRewrite but came up against several issues:

1. The ASTRewrite works on a complete translation unit while my need is to work on a specific node
2. The ASTRewrite records only the modifications without showing the final result

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the moment I use string manipulation for doing this - don't know if there is a better solution...